# Parse notification not working with Android 9

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

After completing a Parse installation for a new user of our app using Android 9, the device token in our Parse's Installation table stays undefined and Parse's notification are not received by the device.

Is there a solution for this problem ?

We are using com.parse:parse-android:1.16.7 and Parse server 2.6.5

Comment: kindly share the problem more clearly in which line you facing the problem....this is not the problem

Comment: I don't know which line of code to show you, the code responsible for populating the device token is somewhere in the Parse SDK lib for Android.

Comment: Noticed this too, using verbose log it comes down to `java.lang.Exception: GCM registration error: GSF_PACKAGE_NOT_AVAILABLE`. Unfortunately no solution so far...